# Input language and other Windows 7 hotkeys reset every time

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

I'm using four input languages: English, Japanese, Chinese and Greek. I'm used to having them on Left ALT+Shift+1, ...+2, ...+3 and ...+4, respectively. But on my Windows 7 computers, Alt+shift+1 and +4 keep resetting themselves after a reboot.

I've also got my internet browser set to Ctrl+Alt+I (Right Alt+I), but this one also disappears after a reboot.

How can I fix this.

Comment: What version of Windows 7 are you using exactly?

Comment: Do you reboot properly? As in, letting Windows save your user settings and not just pressing the power button or something? If you really can't find a solution, I suggest just using alt-shift to cycle through them and get the right one. This one won't be going away, eh.

Comment: @Ramhound: W7 Home Premium

Comment: @Ariane: It reboots properly.

Comment: Are you trying to modify a company company or personal computer?  When your setting reset do the languages disappear or simply the configuration of the ALT+SHIFT+NUM resets?

Comment: @Ramhound It's a personal computer. The configurations reset, so I either have to ALT+SHIFT to scroll through the languages, or reconfigure the hotkeys.

Comment: I have the same problem. Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. Company computer but we don't run AD, so each of us in the software development team administers his/her own machine. My input method hotkeys have also been getting reset every time the machine reboots. This is a new machine and I always let the computer shut down properly. I have tried to capture what process is messing with the registry keys for hotkeys using procmon.exe, but I get nothing relevant so far.

Comment: It appears that it really is Windows not *loading* the hotkey settings properly. If I open the Registry Editor, I can see that the hotkey mappings are still in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method\Hot Keys` key. It's just Windows not using them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with input language hotkeys resetting and managed to work around by deleting the contents of the registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method\Hot Keys
```

After rebooting, I reassigned the hotkeys and Windows now seems to remember them.